Can mdframed (or tcolorbox) create a box with the title at the bottom and protruding from the body box?
I would like to create a custom shaded box environment with a title box --- but with the title at the bottom of the environment instead of the top.  Additionally, I would like the title to be right-aligned and protruding a specified amount from the body of the environment (and with potentially different color).
Can mdframed be coaxed into creating something like that?  Or if not, how about tcolorbox?
UPDATE: I changed the question to specify that the title box should protrude from the body box.

You get the manual of tcolorbox probably by typing texdoc tcolorbox on the command line.
On p. 179 you'll find, what you need. Example:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}
\begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced,title=My title,
attach boxed title to bottom right]
This is a \textbf{tcolorbox}.
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}



Thank you for your response.  It is amazingly simple with tcolorbox.  But now I further specified what I meant by "different margins" in my original question.  I actually want the title box to protrude from the body box.

@ltcomdata Well, I have given you an idea how to start.
